# NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `order_item' for #<Order:0x00000009dd52a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models, `Order, order_item`, and `food_item`
An `order has_many order_items` and an `order_item has_many food_items`

When I create a new order from my order_controller API I am getting the below error which am not sure whats wrong.

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `order_item' for #<Order:0x00000009dd52a8>
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::OrdersController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.json? }
  before_action :fetch_restaurent
  before_action :fetch_food_items, :only => [:index]
  after_action :send_order_to_kitchen, :only => [:create, :update]

  def index
    @orders = Restaurant.orders.fetch_items_from_ethor
  end

  def show
   # Display the list of food_items available from the restaurant
   # Allow the customer to place an order 
  end

  def create  
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
    render :json, order, status:201, location: [:api, current_customer, order]
    else
    render :json, { errors: order.errors }, status:422
  end
  end

  # once the order is placed just send it to the kitechn()
  def update
    @order = Order.find_by(params[:id])
    @rder.update_attributes(order_params)
    if @order.save
      render :json, order, status: 201, location: [:api, current_user.order.id]
    else
      render :json,{errors: order.errors}, status: 422
    end
  end


  private
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :order_id, :pos_id, :table_id, :order_number, 
        :order_status,:order_date,  :food_item_ids)
    end
  end
```

order.rb # model file

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :table
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :food_items, through: :order_items
  validates :customer_id, :order_number, presence:true
  validates :subtotal, :final_total, presence:true, numericality:{ greater_than_or_equal_to:0   }
end
```

order_item.rb # model

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :food_item, inverse_of: :order_items
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :order_items
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :food_items
end
```

food_item.rb # model

```
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :food_items
  belongs_to :order_item, inverse_of: :food_items
  has_many :categories_food_items
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_food_items
end
```

I do not understand from where it is asking for order_item. Please help me to understand fix this problem.

```
undefined method `order_item' for #<Order:0x00000009dd52a8>
```

My stack trace:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/orders?access_token=testing&order[customer_id]=1&order[order_number]=101&order[pos_id]=222&order[table_id]=1&order[order_status]=pending&order[order_date]=02/03/2015" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-22 14:39:30 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by Api::V1::OrdersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"access_token"=>"testing", "order"=>{"customer_id"=>"1", "order_number"=>"101", "pos_id"=>"222", "table_id"=>"1", "order_status"=>"pending", "order_date"=>"02/03/2015"}}
  ApiKey Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `api_keys`.* FROM `api_keys`  WHERE `api_keys`.`access_token` = 'testing' LIMIT 1
  Restaurant Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `restaurants`.* FROM `restaurants`  WHERE `restaurants`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms
** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:         
  Environment Monitored? false         
  API key set? true

NoMethodError - undefined method `order_items' for #<Class:0x0000000a70f0f8>:
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
  app/controllers/api/v1/orders_controller.rb:24:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  searchkick (0.8.7) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:107:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  xray-rails (0.1.16) lib/xray/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  airbrake (4.2.0) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  airbrake (4.2.0) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (4.2.0) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.5) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please update your post with full error stacktrace.

Comment: In update method, you have `@rder`, is it expected?

Comment: You have order_params and inside there is order_id and order_number ... there it looks more like a has_one order_item behavior... maybe you want to inspect your params and have a look if you permit all the right params.

Comment: user934801: Nothing works what you said. The params are permited.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason why it is saying `undefined method`order_item' for #`

I am actually validating the order_item inside the order model. Which am not supposed to.

After changing my order model as below(removing validation on order_item) the problem got solved.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :table
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :food_items, through: :order_items

  validates :customer_id, :order_number, presence:true
  validates :subtotal, :final_total, presence:true, numericality:{ greater_than_or_equal_to:0   }
```